# How to change date format through velocity email script in Marketo?

Tags: email, scripting, velocity, marketo

I am trying to format date stored in lead object via velocity email script token and it is not working, please anyone got same issue??

Here is what I did in Email Script token.

```
#set($myDate = $convert.parseDate(${lead.eventdate}, "dd-MM-yyyy"))
#set($formattedDate = $date.format("yyyy-MM-dd", $myDate))
${formattedDate}
```

When I see lead.eventdate it is stored like 23 Mar 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trick was while parsing date, my Client is using French instance of marketo so when I see date in lead database was different then what it is actually stored.

finally slight change in parsing worked.

```
#set($myDate = $convert.parseDate(${lead.eventdate}, 'MMM dd, yyyy'))
#set($formattedDate = $date.format('dd/MM/yyyy', ${myDate}))
${formattedDate}
```